# Ajax sort table php without refresh page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo, pagination

When i click on the books link, it should sort the books in ascending order, and if i click again it should sort them in descending order.
Why is it that when i'm on the first page and click on the books link it sorts the books but only if i click twice and when i'm on the second page for example and click on the link, the sort is performed but it returns me to the first page. Why ?

this as my ajax code in index.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sorter").click(function() {
  // e.preventDefault();
  var order_by_value = $('input[name="order_by"]').val();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "" + 'http://test.local/ajax-data.php?action=getBooks',
      data:{
        'order_by_value': order_by_value,
        //button: 'button',
      },
      success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        if(order_by_value == "ASC"){
          $('input[name="order_by"]').val("DESC");
        } else {
          $('input[name="order_by"]').val("ASC");
        }
        // $('input[name="current"]').trigger('click');
        // display the result from the server
        $("#myTable").html(res);
      }
   });
  });
});
```

And this my Function to get the Books in UUser.php

```
public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2, $order = "ASC")
{
   $sql_start = $start * $limit;
   $sql_limit = $limit;
   $sql_order_by = $order;

   $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook, userBook.book_id, userBook.user_id FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username ORDER BY Library.nameOfBook $sql_order_by LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
   $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
   $statment->execute([
       ':username' => $this->username
   ]);

   $result = $statment->fetchAll();

   echo "<table id='myTable' border='1'>
           <tr>
             <th><a id='sorter' href='#'>Books</a></th>
             <th>Action</th>
           </tr>";
   foreach($result as $row){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' id='delete".$row['book_id']."-".$row['user_id']."' onclick='deleteBook(this)' name='delete' value='Delete'>" . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";
   echo "";
   return count($result); 
}
```

And this is the file that ajax called it

```
<?php

include_once('UUser.php');

if(isset($_GET['action']) )
{

  $object = new User();
  switch($_GET['action'])
  {
    case "getBooks":
      $object->setUserName($_SESSION['username']);
      $object->getBooks();
      break;
    default:
      echo('there is no action');
      break;
  }
}
?>
```